# How to get base URL in a Lithium template/view?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web, lithium

I want to access a folder named 'Videos'. It is placed parallel to images/scripts etc. I can send the base url in a variable from the controller but it doesn't make sense. Is there a way I can access the folder in a template/view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate a base URL, you can do `$this->url("/")`, but for paths to assets, there's `$this->path("/")`, which hooks into the `Media` class. Often these values will be the same, but `Media` allows you to have more sophisticated asset configurations, and `path()` keeps your generated paths in sync with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate! Where do I look in the documentation for these methods? The documentation needs a search!

Comment: Yeah I agree it needs a little help. Here you go: http://li3.me/docs/lithium/net/http/Media::path()

Comment: Technically... `$this` in the template refers to an instance of `lithium\view\Renderer` and the `url()` and `path()` functions are defined in the `_init()` method. See http://li3.me/docs/lithium/template/view/Renderer::_init(). When you call `$this->path()` in a template, it's invoking `Renderer::__call()` which finds `$this->handlers['url']` and invokes that, which calls `Media::asset()`, which calls `Media::filterAssetPath()` and ultimately `Media::path()`. All the hooks for filters and dependency injection make the li3 source a little tricky to follow, but they have a purpose.